Show image from Camera capture on TSkPaintbox
I'm trying to show a photo after capturing it by the camera, but it doesn't work at all, the way I did it is wrong?
procedure TMyPhotoEdit.ActionCameraDidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
var
   Item: TListBoxItem;
   LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Image.SaveToStream(LStream);
  LStream.Position := 0;

  SkPaintBox1.Canvas.LoadFontFromStream(LStream);
  LStream.DisposeOf;

I want to show the photo on the Canvas.

LoadFontFromStream? Probably LoadFromStream

You can draw the photo onto a TSkPaintBox inside the SkPaintBox1.OnDraw event, after converting it from TBitmap into ISkImage.
So, first declare FSkImage: ISkImage; as form field (and make sure to free it when the form is destroyed).
Then, handle the SkPaintBox1.OnDraw event:
procedure TMyPhotoEdit.SkPaintBox1Draw(ASender: TObject; const ACanvas: ISkCanvas; ....);
begin
  if FSkImage <> nil then
    ACanvas.DrawImage(FSkImage, 0, 0);
end;

Last, change your action method to only convert the photo to ISkImage and to trigger a draw event:
procedure TMyPhotoEdit.ActionCameraDidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
var
   Item: TListBoxItem;
   LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Image.SaveToStream(LStream);
  LStream.Position := 0;
  FSkImage := TSkImage.MakeFromEncodedStream(LStream);

  SkPaintBox1.Redraw();
  LStream.DisposeOf;

